# React List box how to transfer other side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dual list box but ı cant transfer the other side ? I have a two button right side and left side
when user click ex:admin and click the right button transfer the other side. How can I do that ? Anyone help ? I am trying but ı couldnt.

I am using react v 0.14 also ı dont want to use any npm[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![List Box[2]][2]

````
menuClick = (activeItem) =>{
    console.log('activeItem' + activeItem);
}

render() {

    var role = ['admin' , 'user' , 'Deneme' , 'Denem1']
    var activeRole =['SuperAdmin']

    return (
      <section >
<div> <h4>Active Role List</h4> </div>

<Card >
  <ul>
      {role.map((activeItem)=> <li  value={activeItem} onClick={() => this.menuClick(activeItem)} >    <a>{activeItem} </a>  </li>   )}
  </ul>
</Card>


<div className="div2"> 
<button><i className="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></button>
<button> <i className="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i> </button> 
</div>

<div className="div3">
<div> <h4>Selected Role List</h4> </div>

<Card className="admin_create_card" id="kryesore">
<ul>
      {activeRole.map((activeItem)=> <li  value={activeItem} onClick={() => this.menuClick(activeItem)} > <a>{activeItem} </a>      </li>   )}

</ul>
</Card>
</div>


</section>
         

)
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/770vw.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oalmT.png
````

Comment: https://ibb.co/PZDphW9